# How to deploy angular 7 app on server on Github?

Tags: angular

I want to deploy my Angular 7 app on the Github Pages but `index.html` could not be copied and getting `404.html`. I get the error every time.

Comment: Do you mean GitHub pages?

Comment: [gh-pagess](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages)

Comment: When you built your angular app did you set your base href to where you github page is located at?

Comment: yes i did it same as  ng build --prod --base-href "https://USERNAME.github.io/REPOSITORY_NAME/"

Answer (score 0):

Use [angular-cli-ghpages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages)

To install the command run the following:

```
npm i angular-cli-ghpages --save-dev
```

Usage:

```
ng build --prod --base-href "https://USERNAME.github.io/REPOSITORY_NAME/"

npx ngh --dir=dist/[PROJECTNAME]
```